# When trying to compile a .dll, I'm getting an error with the interface keyword

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, interface

I have set up a project in Visual Studio to create a .dll. I have included an external library in the project which uses the keyword "interface". This is giving me the following error:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'INuiAudioBeam'

These are the lines of code where the error occurs:

```
#ifndef __INuiAudioBeam_FWD_DEFINED__
#define __INuiAudioBeam_FWD_DEFINED__
typedef interface INuiAudioBeam INuiAudioBeam; //Error on this line
#endif
```

The above code is part of a header file in the external library I have included. The project builds successfully without any errors when compiling without including the headers for the library (Note: Linking the library does not cause any problems).

What is the solution to this? Is it because I have an external library I'm using to create my dll? Should I create a .lib instead of a dll?

Comment: This is not C++ syntax, but Google says MS added the interface keyword to managed C++. You probably need to tell VS the Kinect library is written in managed C++ somehow.

Comment: Are you including `NuiApi.h`? @busy_wait There is no `interface` keyword in managed C++. Managed C++ uses the `__interface` keyword. C++/CLI offer the compound keywords `interface class` and `interface struct`. The `interface` you see here is a COM artifact. Additionally, the Kinect system is implemented in native code and exposes its services through COM to be easily consumable by native and managed code alike.

Comment: This is standard spew in any .h file generated by MIDL for a COM interface.  I'd have to guess that you disabled the Microsoft specific language extensions in your project, /Za option.

Comment: Thanks for the help fellas, __interface seemed to work.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else searches this, the problem is most likely

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

Before

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Remove the define, make sure your including windows.h, and that should define interface keyword for you

Comment: For who is trying to build a DLL with VisualStudio, the `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` line is in the stdafx.h file. Just comment it and everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can get C2146 with indictment of the interface keyword. It may be confusing as to how a keyword may be undefined, especially that in other compilation units or projects that use the same header file - the inclusion of which brought about the problem - all goes smooth. However, the apparent keyword "interface" is still a compiler #define directive. It just happens to be buried inside a header file that a few developers have reasons to inspect: the `<objbase.h>`. There it is defined in two steps:

```
#define __STRUCT__ struct
#define interface __STRUCT__
```

Since the `<objbase.h>` is included by multiple other header files - such as ole2.h, oleauto.h, and a slew of ATL headers - you may be surprised with this error when none of those headers were included in the current compilation unit.